# Emulador de terminal em Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, console, terminal

Olá! Todos que já trabalharam com Java pelo menos uma vez já devem ter visto códigos destinados a uso em terminal (console), como o método `println()`, localizado em `System.out`.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum emulador de terminal para o Java Swing. Só por curiosidade mesmo! Por exemplo: tenho uma janela Swing, e dentro dela preciso de um componente que "rode" instruções para o terminal (console). Aqui o bloquinho:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Preparando-se para explodir...");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("3");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("2");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("1");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("KABUUUUUUUUUUUUUUM!!!!");
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Caso não tenham entendido, pensem naqueles instaladores de programas (os famosos Next, next, finish). Neles há um componente que te mostra o decorrer da instalação (criação de pastas, configurações, etc.). Isto seria o `System.out.println()`.

Então, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Na verdade o métoto println, não está associado a um console, é um um PrintStream que é um OutputStream, ele pode estar associado até com um arquivo.

Comment: Pense assim: o Eclipse mostra um console em programas, certo? Tem como eu colocar esse "console" na janela Swing?

Comment: Faltou eu dar esta referencia:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Comment: Acho que sim. Por exemplo: se você usar um inputText do swing, você consegue escrever comandos pro terminal e ler o resultados dos mesmos e por onde você quiser usando a classe Runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabriel, isso é fácil de fazer utilizando um [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html). Eu criei um pequeno exemplo utilizando um arquivo só para você testar aí.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

import java.awt.Color;

public class TerminalFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private StyledDocument doc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TerminalFrame terminal = new TerminalFrame();
                    terminal.setVisible(true);
                    terminal.print("Hello bloody world!"); // Using print() to print to the "Swing Terminal".
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TerminalFrame() {
        setTitle("Terminal Simulation");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        textPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
    }

    public void print(String s) {
        try {
            doc.insertString(0, s+"\n", null);
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }

}
```

Como poderá ver, eu criei um método na classe TerminalFrame (Que extende JFrame) chamado print(), que pega uma String, e ele adiciona essa String ao StyledDocument associado ao JTextFrame. Com este modelo de código você pode personalizar o terminal à vontade (Eu deixei com o background preto e com o foreground verde já). Dá pra você colocar um Carret customizado que pisca como nos terminais antigos, dá pra trocar a fonte pra ficar mais oldschool ainda, e enfim, é simples.