# Alternativa ao Scanner para entrada de dados

Tags: java, entrada-de-dados

Em java, quando estamos aprendendo a capturar entrada de dados, geralmente por modo de texto, somos instruídos a utilizar a classe [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Há alguma alternativa ao `Scanner` para capturar entrada de dados por modo de texto? Se sim, como funciona?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532416/1518921):

### Classe [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) e [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

---

#### Classe [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
int i = dis.readInt();
```

O `readLine` no `DataInputStream` está descontinuado, pra pegar o valor da `String` você pode usar a solução anterior com `BufferedReader`.

---

#### Classe [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

```
Console console = System.console();
String s = console.readLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
```

Parece que este método não funciona em alguma IDEs.

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se seria uma alternativa viável, porém você pode usar [`JOptionPane`](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/java/showinputdialog.php) pra pegar entrada de dados.

```
String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entre com um nome: ");
```

Comment: Interessante sugestão, mas como ele disse é *por modo de texto*, mas deixe como sugestão alternativa pra quem trabalha `java.swing` (seria interessante adicionar esse detalhe na resposta). Por falar nisso achei um exemplo legal com java.swing: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72032/3635 +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, eu pensei que não seria uma alternativa 100% viável mas aproveitei por causa do titulo. Vou olhar esse exemplo com swing :D